# SQL queries break our game! (Back-end server is at capacity)

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

We have a Facebook game that stores all persistent data in a MySQL database that is running on a large Amazon RDS instance. One of our tables is 2GB in size. If I run any queries on that table that take more than a couple of seconds, any SQL actions performed by our game will fail with the error:

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity

This obviously brings down our game!

I've monitored CPU usage on the RDS instance during these periods, and though it does spike, it doesn't go much over 50%. Previously we were on a smaller instance size and it did hit 100%, so I'd hoped just throwing more CPU capacity at the problem would solve it. I now think it's an issue with the number of open connections. However, I've only been working with SQL for 8 months or so, so I'm no expert on MySQL configuration.

Is there perhaps some configuration setting I can change to prevent these queries from overloading the server, or should I just not be running them whilst our game is up?

I'm using MySQL Workbench to run the queries.

Any help would be very much appreciated - Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's an example....

```
SELECT * 
FROM BlueBoxEngineDB.Transfer 
WHERE Amount = 1000 
AND FromUserId = 4 
AND Status='Complete';
```

The table looks like this:

```
TransferId  Started  Status  Expires  FromUserId  ToUserId  CurrencyId  Amount  SessionId

1177    2012-06-04 21:43:18 Added       150001      2           4           1   12156
1179    2012-06-04 21:48:50 ISF         150001      2           4           1   12156
1181    2012-06-04 22:08:33 Added       150001      2           4           25  12156
1183    2012-06-04 22:08:41 Complete    150001      2           4           50  12156
1185    2012-06-04 22:08:46 Added       150001      2           4           200 12156
```

Comment: I'm assuming that big table already has the appropriate indexes?

Comment: Even if the table is 2GB, queries generally shouldn't take more than a few seconds if you're not getting super complex with them.  Please post an example query, an `EXPLAIN` of that query, and the table structure. Are the queries coming from the game writing to the table you're running the query on?  If so, it could be a locking issue.

Comment: I just took it out with this simple query:

SELECT * FROM BlueBoxEngineDB.Transfer WHERE Amount = 1000 AND FromUserId = 4;

Comment: I read as far as `SELECT *` .. first issue.  Do you really need all of the columns?

Comment: I agree with G-Nugget and Michael.  Do you have an index of FromUserId, Status and Amount?  Individual indexes and one combined for luck?  You could also try the SQL Database Engine Tuning Advisor.  Put a typical workload of SQL queries into it, it will suggest indexes and statistics and partitioning for you.

Comment: Never mind that, you're on MySQL..

Comment: Serious answer: hire a really good DBA.  It sounds like your problems are going well beyond the scope of a Q and A site.  If this is a real business, get good employees.  EDIT: Scratch that - just get someone to consult for a day or a week.

Comment: This sounds like it's  more appropriate for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) than it is for StackOverflow.

Comment: If we could afford a DBA we'd hire one in a second. We're a startup though and we're at the limit of our budget. That means it's up to me! :P

Comment: So...can you post an `EXPLAIN` of that query and the table structure?

Comment: I've posted the table structure. What needs explaining regarding the query?

Comment: @TimH You haven't posted the table structure to the point where it tells us anything useful about the indexes which are likely impacting the query performace. Run a `SHOW CREATE TABLE BlueBoxEngineDB` and post the results.

Comment: ... also see [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) for how to obtain the execution plain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should REALLY consider running a high availability RDS and setting up a read replica off of it.  That way you can run complex queries on the replica to your heart's content and not interfere with the production database.

A 2GB (in size) database is really not all that large.  If you have the proper indexes on the tables you are trying to query, you should not be locking your DB up.

Above all - don't be running queries on a high capacity production database if you don't know what it is going to do. From the comments above it seems clear that you are not a very experienced DB admin.  That's ok. Working on a high volume server will definitely be a learning experience for you, just try not to make your lessons ones where you crash your service. Again, this is why having a replica, or creating a DB snapshot and setting up a test DB before trying queries on large tables is a very good idea.

Comment: Actually, just finished doing this when I saw your response. It works great! :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to tweak your schema ([adding indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) is the immediate step).

To analyze your situation you can access the MySQL slow query logs for your database to determine if there are slow-running SQL queries and, if so, the performance characteristics of each. You could set the "slow_query_log" DB Parameter and query the mysql.slow_log table to review the slow-running SQL queries. Please refer to the [Amazon RDS User Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.CommonDBATasks.html) to learn more.

There are probably some of your tables that you should consider offloading to [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/). Both of them will give a latency of single-digit milliseconds, and therefore are very popular among game developers. You just need to think about your [data structure](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#What_is_the_Data_Model).

Answer (score 1):

An index on `(FromUserId, Amount, Status)` would probably help this query a lot.

You may have though a lot more variations of queries that hit this table. Adding an index for every one of them, will end you in having tens of indexes in the table and this may bring other problems.

Try to analyze the slow query log and then optimize the slowest queries (and the ones that use more percentage of the CPU).